# Ubuntu 19.04 only recognizes 8GB RAM out of 16GB

Tags: hardware, 19.04, ram

I just added another 8GB of RAM to my HP 250 G4 but the system does not recognize it. Any idea why?

**sudo lshw -class memory**

```
*-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: Insyde
       physical id: 0
       version: F.1E
       date: 12/25/2015
       size: 128KiB
       capacity: 6080KiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppytoshiba int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int9keyboard int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 6
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 32KiB
       capacity: 32KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back instruction
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 7
       slot: L2 Cache
       size: 256KiB
       capacity: 256KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 8
       slot: L3 Cache
       size: 3MiB
       capacity: 3MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-cache
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 5
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 32KiB
       capacity: 32KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back data
       configuration: level=1
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 25
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 8GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: SODIMM DDR Synchronous 1600 MHz (0,6 ns) [empty]
          product: 99U5428-063.A00LF
          vendor: Kingston
          physical id: 0
          serial: 19532259
          slot: Bottom - Slot 1 (left)
          clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0,6 ns)
          product: M471B1G73EB0-YK0
          vendor: Samsung
          physical id: 1
          serial: 15262215
          slot: Bottom - Slot 2 (right)
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97973/discussion-on-question-by-alexbor-ubuntu-19-04-only-recognizes-8gb-ram-out-of-16).

Answer (score 3):

**Major update! The max RAM on this machine is 8G, as per https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c04605376**

---

It appears that you've installed memory that exceeds the maximum RAM specs for this computer. See Update #1 for how to check/upgrade your BIOS for a possible fix.

```
description: SODIMM **DDR** Synchronous 1600 MHz (0,6 ns) [**empty**]

description: SODIMM **DDR3** Synchronous 1600 MHz (0,6 ns)
```

*Note: the user's BIOS only sees the original 8G RAM*

---

**Update #1:**

- Make sure that memory XMP is disabled in the BIOS, and that the CPU is not overclocked.
- Check your BIOS version with `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`, and if it's not version F.29 Rev.A from June 21, 2019, go to https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-250-g4-notebook-pc/7609933 and get the new version and install it.
- To test the memory, go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest`. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory.

**Update #2:**

- user currently has BIOS F.1E

Comment: This is not an Ubuntu issue, so the question should be closed as off-topic.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try with updating BIOS. Keep you guys posted.

Comment: @AlexBor status please...

Comment: @heynnema Status: I just woke up. :) On the serious side updating BIOS doesn't seem as an easy task. I will need to do some reading.

Comment: @AlexBor have you checked what version BIOS you have now? What version do you have now? Updating the BIOS is usually very easy. Download the newer BIOS. Flash it. Done.

Comment: Bios version: **F.1E**

Comment: @AlexBor so... update the BIOS and see if you see all 16G... maybe... maybe not.

Comment: I tried to update BIOS. I downloaded latest version (F.29 Rev.A), created recovery USB flash drive, followed this [instruction](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c00042629) and get to the point here I just don't have option to select Firmware Management or BIOS Management in Hardware Diagnostics UEFI menu.

Comment: I looked at the instructions for using a USB flash drive, and they are a little weird. Try using the first menu choice that says "Update the BIOS", or if you still have Windows installed, try following one of the other two methods they outline.

Comment: Once you get the new BIOS installed, and you've rebooted your computer, if the BIOS and Ubuntu see 16G RAM, please remember to accept my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Recovery USB flash drive was created by colleague of mine, on Windows of course.
And I will accept your answer for sure. But I am bit stuck now. Every screenshot in that instruction looks like my BIOS/UEFI but it does not have that option in that third step.

Comment: @AlexBor Do you have Windows installed on your computer? Have you tried any of the alternate methods outlined at the link that you gave?

Comment: That's the thing, I don't have Windows installed and never had on this machine. That's why I did _Recovery USB flash drive_  method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98248/discussion-between-alexbor-and-heynnema).

Comment: @AlexBor  Sorry I missed you in chat. You might try calling HP to see 1) if that new BIOS removes the 8G RAM limitation, and 2) discuss the screwy BIOS update instructions.

Comment: @AlexBor status please...

Comment: I don't know how to update BIOS. So I am giving up...

Comment: @AlexBor Did you contact HP?